# Limit memory bandwidth cgroups without NUMA

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel, embedded-linux, cgroups

I am trying to limit the bandwidth of a process to the memory.
I have 2 cgroups (cgroup1 and cgroup2) with processes in them. I can limit the amount of memory is that used by each cgroup. 
But if they keep calling `malloc()` and `free()` and saturating the memory bus, they influence each other.

How do I limit this? I don't have two different memory nodes, and no NUMA.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. [Supported subsystems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) are:

- blkio — this subsystem sets limits on input/output access to and from block devices such as physical drives (disk, solid state, USB, etc.).
- cpu — this subsystem uses the scheduler to provide cgroup tasks access to the CPU.
- cpuacct — this subsystem generates automatic reports on CPU resources used by tasks in a cgroup.
- cpuset — this subsystem assigns individual CPUs (on a multicore system) and memory nodes to tasks in a cgroup.
- devices — this subsystem allows or denies access to devices by tasks in a cgroup.
- freezer — this subsystem suspends or resumes tasks in a cgroup.
- memory — this subsystem sets limits on memory use by tasks in a cgroup, and generates automatic reports on memory resources used by those tasks.
- net_cls — this subsystem tags network packets with a class identifier (classid) that allows the Linux traffic controller (tc) to identify packets originating from a particular cgroup task.
- net_prio — this subsystem provides a way to dynamically set the priority of network traffic per network interface.
- ns — the namespace subsystem.

A recent systems [research paper](http://pertsserver.cs.uiuc.edu/~mcaccamo/papers/euromicro12.pdf) introduced a new controller to achieve this and has made the associated code [available](https://github.com/heechul/linux/tree/sched-3.2-throttle-v2).

An alternative would be to mmap a file and then set `blkio` settings on it (not sure if this would work). Then, have your program read/write variables from the file instead of using `malloc` (ugly!).

Comment: I noticed indeed what you said above. I hoped some1 like you would have noticed a paper on a possible solution. thank you very much appreciated